# UIPageViewController subviewcontroller can't perform segue on viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I have a UIPageController which contains two subviewcontrollers. On start, I'm trying to perform a segue from SubViewControllerOne to LoginViewController when a user isn't authorized. I have a segue in viewDidAppear like so:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "authorizeSegue", sender: self);
```

This produces an unsuccessful segue and a warning

```
Warning: Attempt to present <Volley.LoginViewController: 0x7f98bd801e00> on <Volley.SubViewControllerOne: 0x7f98bd608400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I've done this in the past with ViewControllers and TabBarViewControllers successfully.

When I wrap the segue in a timer, or trigger through an IBAction, the segue works perfectly fine. I believe it has something to do with the PageViewController.

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var subViewControllers = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = [];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let subViewControllerOne = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubViewControllerOne") as! SubViewControllerOne
        let subViewControllerTwo = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubViewControllerTwo") as! SubViewControllerTwo
        subViewControllers = [yourPodcastViewController, appearancesViewController]
        setViewControllers([subViewControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
```

The navigation controller and PageViewController
[image]

The segue from SubViewControllerOne to LoginViewController
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think because of view controller life cycle you should perform segue into `viewWillApear`

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I've had this issue before when running segues via didSelect on tableviews. The solution is to wrap it in the main thread. Not sure why this is necessary, but it solves my problem.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "authorizeSegue", sender: self);
}
```